# Go - Read data from TCP connection from multiple readers

Tags: networking, tcp, go, network-programming

I'm working on Cloud Server's networking thing using Go programming language.
And I faced a problem with **reading same TCPconn at the same time from different Goroutines**.

Here is a simple example

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    addr, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", ":8888")
    listener, _ := net.ListenTCP("tcp", addr)

    for {
        conn, err := listener.AcceptTCP()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        go Handle(conn) // output always coming from here
        go Handle(conn)
    }
}

func Handle(conn *net.TCPConn) {
    data := make([]byte, 1024)
    fmt.Println("Ok")
    for {
        len_data, err := conn.Read(data)
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println(len_data)
    }
}
```

In this example console output always coming from 1st goroutine `go Handle(conn)` ...

How to make Read functionality from 2 Goroutines at the same time ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is using [`io.MultiWriter`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiWriter) and [`io.Pipe`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Pipe):

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    r := strings.NewReader(hello)
    pr1, pw1 := io.Pipe()
    pr2, pw2 := io.Pipe()
    pr3, pw3 := io.Pipe()
    mw := io.MultiWriter(pw1, pw2, pw3)

    wg.Add(4)
    go process(&wg, 0, pr1)
    go process(&wg, 1, pr2)
    go process(&wg, 2, pr3)
    go func() {
        io.Copy(mw, r)
        pw1.Close()
        pw2.Close()
        pw3.Close()
        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/ZIU6RZ79ZG)

Comment: Or, [using slices of arbitrary size](https://play.golang.org/p/IYZ-Jnq4g3) rather than a hard coded fan out of three (and that also passes any read error along to each processor).

Answer (score 0):

Start a single go routine to perform conn.Read(data) and put the result into a channel.

Then (concurrently, without waiting for the first go routine to finish) start multiple go routines to read from this channel.

You don't want to directly read from the conn concurrently from multiple go routine since it is not thread-safe (the fact that it runs, and only run only on a single go routine probably because your MAXGOPROCS == 1).

Comment: That means he'd have to keep all the data in memory.

Comment: Not if he set a proper buffer size for the channel.

Comment: no? he'd have to create a channel per request, read all the data to a buffer, send it through the channel.

Comment: I guess you (or me?) misunderstood his question. He's trying to fan out the read. Not multicast the read.

Comment: The way I understood it is that he wanted to multicast it, you could be right.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so first of all. You're doing it wrong friend.

What you should do is create workers (pre-create), create channel and aggregate that channel with incoming connections. Than you should take that same connection inside of worker and handle it. On this way you'll get X concurrent workers that runs against your connections.

I went ahead and wrote you down one nice example of how to gracefully handle workers but did not had time to write down how to gracefully handle incoming connections. Never the less, you'll see what i mean.

http://play.golang.org/p/YkQVmBEWly

Hope this helps,